# ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest on redirect with GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build a index page with a form displayed inside a modal. After the form is submitted with POST action as JS, triggers `#create` action that responds with `redirect_to` action `#index` also as JS, like this

```
def create
  @output = Output.new(output_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @output.save
      format.html { redirect_to @output, notice: 'Output was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @output }
      format.js { redirect_to production_line_path @output.machine.production_line, machine_id: @output.machine_id, format: :js }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @output.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

My problem is that this gives an error with the following description

Security warning: an embedded `<script>` tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.

Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 35ms (Views: 27.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)

ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest (Security warning: an embedded `<script>` tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.):

I am not sure if I am trying to do this the wrong way. Would I have to change response for JS to not redirect, but rather render from the same controller action `#create`?

Comment: Why are you redirecting in `format.js` instead of rendering a JS file?

Comment: @emaillenin - Not sure, as I wrote I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this. At first I thought that I should have rendering action called from the controller of the model that I want to display.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the built in redirect_to and pass it a path and params, or you can redirect using JS.  If you want to redirect do this:

```
render js: "window.location.pathname = #{production_line_path @output.machine.production_line, machine_id: @output.machine_id}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I discovered what was the cause of `InvalidCrossOriginRequest` error. By mistake my form was sending as JS request without token that normally is automatically added by UJS Rails adapter, but if one uses it.

My form was missing `remote: true` and instead included `format: :js`, which made me think I was using UJS Rails adapter and that my POST requests were with needed token for CSRF protection. More at [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#csrf-countermeasures)