# Rails ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest on a js request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, csrf

I know this has been brought up [a few times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866223/actioncontrollerinvalidcrossoriginrequest-on-redirect-with-get) on SO but I cannot make inroads. I'm on Rails 5.0.7.2.

I am getting `ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest` thrown hundreds of times per day. Rollbar says it is mostly caused by Bingbot, and it's on my user signup modal, which is from Devise. It's a GET request, and the path is `/users/sign_up`.

**NOTE: It's not a form.** It's a modal that simply asks the user *How would you like to sign up? Email, Fb, Google auth, etc.*

Basically I have some javascript actions on my site, picture like a reddit or stackoverflow upvote. I am *not* using `remote: true` on those links, but rather I have an `$.ajax` call that handles the upvote like so:

```
var token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;

$.ajax({
  // For the upvote, type will be POST
  type: $this.data('method'),
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token)
  },
  url: $this.data('url'),
  success: function(data) {
    // Some cleanup...
  }
});
```

Once a logged out visitor tries to upvote, it fires the ajax request which is then halted (not authorized) and redirected, like this:

```
Started POST "/upvotes/toggle_vote"
Processing by UpvotesController#toggle_vote as */*
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_up"
Processing by RegistrationsController#new as */*
```

Here's the Devise controller which I've overwritten:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    # ... other code        

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js   { render layout: false }
      format.html { respond_with self.resource }
    end
  end
end
```

Inside of `/views/devise/registrations` I have `new.js.erb` which opens up the "how would you like to sign up?" modal.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED:**

- I don't think solving it by adding `protect_from_forgery except: :new` is the right answer (as has been proposed in similar questions), since that's inherently not safe.
- I tried reordering the `respond_to` formats per [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13345#issuecomment-71114660) but that makes the signup modal not open.
- I tried to throw in a `format.any { raise ActionController::RoutingError.new("Not Found") }` catch-all in the `respond_to` block but that did nothing to fix the error.
- As you can see in the `$.ajax` call above I even try to set the `X-CSRF-Token` header.

The full error text by the way is this:

`ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest: Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript`

Any ideas?

Could it be that the authenticity token is getting lost since `UpvotesController#toggle_vote` redirects to `RegistrationsController#new` and changes from a POST to a GET?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails InvalidCrossOriginRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310187/rails-invalidcrossoriginrequest)

Comment: It does not unfortunately, because I think `protect_from_forgery` should be there for security. There was no other proposed solution in that thread. Also, I am not mixing http/https resources.

Comment: how about: `protect_from_forgery unless: -> { request.format.js? }`, only for your some javascript actions.

Comment: Can you share your code for the  javascript action (front end)? And also - are you using jquery-rails or rails-ujs?

Comment: @Joel_Blum I'm using jquery-rails. I cleaned up the question a bit, you can now see my `$.ajax` call.

Comment: @DelPiero I have literally the exact same scenario as you describe. I don't see any solutions here other than the lazy "protect_from_forgery". Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 3):

Couple of thoughts:

1. You shouldn't put the csrf token yourself, both [jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L63) or [rails-ujs](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/utils/ajax.coffee#L58) (I'm not sure which one you're using) do it for you; with rails-ujs you need to use the `Rails.ajax` method
2. [There is no redirecting POST to GET and keeping the original POST headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985596/redirect-to-using-post-in-rails) , that means you indeed lose the csrf token in GET request (however you usually don't send or need a CSRF token in a GET request anyway so check why you are doing that maybe).

Comment: Regarding #1, I am using jquery-rails. Regarding #2, you are right, that all makes sense. If you look at the log output in my question, it's from the way Devise behaves. It tries to run the `/upvotes/toggle_vote` action, which is protected by `before_action :authenticate_user!`. So then control is passed to `RegistrationsController#new`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to send an authenticity token with ajax requests that modify resources in the server (post/put/patch/delete). Usually, rails add it for you as a hidden field in the form.

Comment: Ah, sorry I edited the question to clarify. The modal is actually not a form.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a form or not, you still need to provide a token for rails to accept the request.

Comment: I have `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` in the head of my application layout. Does that not cover that?

Comment: if you're doing an ajax (js) request, try grabbing that token and attach it to the request:
```const token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content```

Comment: Check out my updated question. Inside of the `$.ajax` call I try to set the authenticity token. However now I'm thinking that since there's a redirect and a switch from POST to GET it might not be sending it through? Is that possible?

Comment: can you show the upvotes controller? @DelPiero

Answer (score 2):

Adding this inside your form should do the trick:

```
<% hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
```

Comment: Sorry I should have specified, the modal is actually *not* a form. I know Devise routes usually are, but in this case the modal that pops up simply asks the user how they'd like to proceed. Sign up with email/facebook/etc.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a CORS issue to me, just like the error suggest there I an API call made fro an embedded javascript which is on a different domain than the one defined on your server. This triggers a CORS error. Usually to fix CORS error you need to add a header Access-Control-Allow-Origin with the the domain of the website in the list of allowed domain.
You can easily do this with the rack cors gem: https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 5 I found that

```
config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms = true
```

avoid the CORS issue on same domain remote calls, but it seems that in Rail 6 is not effective.